# The argument type 'BuildContext?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'. The method 'read' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio

[image]
I have tried many ways and still can't fix it
The argument type 'BuildContext?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'. The method 'read' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that, `scaffoldState.currentContext` can return null. you can do a null check and then use it like

```
if(scaffoldState.currentContext != null)ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext)...
```

I dont prefer using `!` directly.

I think you can use the parameter context.

```dart
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)...
```